# Avoiding large memory commit size in a Windows process

Tags: delphi, winapi, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on a 32 bit app (VC++ main exe and a couple of Delphi dlls) that slowly leaked memory (over weeks or months). While I fixed the leaks, one problem still remains - while the working set and active working memory set remain relatively low (about 50Mb), the commit size keeps creeping up to about 1.7Gb.

I do realize that Windows (especially Windows 10) can be pretty aggressive committing memory in a process, but still, I see no obvious reason for this to happen.

I patched `VirtialAlloc` / `VirtialAllocEx` / `VirtialAlloc2` / etc. using Detours to see when VC++ and Delphi memory managers would be forced to request more memory from the OS, but after a few initial requests on startup, I see no calls to those functions while the commit size is still slowly growing.

What else can be responsible for the commit size growth? Any I/O operations? Memory mapped files?

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: Memory Commit Size growing, eventually causing the process to run out of address space.

Comment: this mean you still have errors and leaks in your code

Comment: `ntdll.ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` you hook ? this is need do first instead `VirtialAlloc` hook. `ZwMapViewOfSection`.. and need look process virtual memory map - what concrete memory space types added. what here data

Comment: There seems to be no relevant settings. Do you want to limit the memory usage of the process? You could use [Job Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects).

Comment: Unlike VirtualAlloc, ZwMapViewOfSection ended up being called by the heap manager (HeapAlloc). And DebugDiag was very helpful in tracking the memory leak -  the code assumed VariantClear() would release VT_BYREF|VT_BSTR variants in our custom marshaler. And extra call to SysFreeString was needed.